# Is it possible to apply tags to only those resources that are created by the defined constructs in AWS CDK application?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Let's say I have a stack that creates a lambda function with logRetention enabled, like so

```
export class MainStack extends Stack {
constructor(scope: Construct, id:string, props:StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    Tags.of(this).add('createdBy','cdk')

    const func = new Function(this, 'function', {
        functionName: 'cdk-function',
        code: Code.fromInline('print(event)'),
        handler: 'lambda.handler',
        runtime: Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
        logRetention: RetentionDays.ONE_DAY
    })
}}
```

When I deploy the above stack it creates two lambda functions, 'cdk-function' and one more lambda to manage log retention. It applies the mentioned tag to both the lambda function since they exist in the same scope, but my intention was to apply the tags to only those resources that I have in my cdk code. I don't want to apply tags to all the automatically created resources by cdk. Is it possible to skip tags for those resources?

Comment: To make sure it's clear - all of those resources are created by CDK constructs. The `Function` construct can create multiple resources, such as an IAM role, Security Groups, etc.

Comment: @gshpychka Yes I know it is created by CDK Function construct, I want to apply tags to only the functions that I have defined in my CDK code not the one created by constructs as a dependency. In this case an extra lambda is created to manage Log Retention and it has those tags.

Comment: The issue is that it's not possible to know where you want the line drawn in the levels of

Comment: I want the line drawn at the resources that I have configured in my cdk code, extra resources created internally by cdk constructs shouldn't inherit the tags. Is it possible?

Comment: CDK constructs are also CDK code. CDK doesn't distinguish between construct you wrote yourself and the ones that are provided out of the box as part of the CDK.

Comment: @gshpychka I got it working by using `Tags.of(func).add('key','value')`, it will tag only the lambda function and not the retention lambda function

Comment: You might want to add that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

A construct can provision an arbitrary number of resources under the hood, and this is true for both the constructs that ship with `aws-cdk-lib` and the ones you write yourself.

Most L2 constructs that ship with CDK have a [default child](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/constructs.Node.html#defaultchild), though, and you can apply your tags to that.

```
Tags.of(func.node.defaultChild).add('createdBy','cdk')
```

This prop is optional, though, and you may need to add a check to ensure it's not undefined.

This will not prevent the tags being propagated to any constructs that are created in the scope of the default child, but this usually never happens with constructs that ship with AWS CDK by default.

Answer (score 0):

Every L2 Construct in AWS CDK has a property called `Node`, and within this Node property you can access all the underlying resources with `func.node.children` which returns an array of all the children resources of that main Construct, then you can access these children and manipulate them as you need (e.g: removing the tags for one child). Hope that help you!